# How to discover the reason for an error in my simple test class?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, aura-framework, test-class

This is my aura method to retrieve fields for dual list box.

```
@AuraEnabled
        public static List <String> getProperties(sObject objObject, string sFieldAPI) {
            List < String > lstOptions = new list < String > ();
            Schema.sObjectType objType = objObject.getSObjectType();
            Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objDescribe = objType.getDescribe();
            map <String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = objDescribe.fields.getMap();
            list < Schema.PicklistEntry > values =fieldMap.get(sFieldAPI).getDescribe().getPickListValues();
            for (Schema.PicklistEntry a: values) {
            lstOptions.add(a.getValue());
            }
            lstOptions.sort();
            return lstOptions;
        }
```

And this is the test class where I'm getting error.

```
testMethod static void testGetProperties(){
    setupInsertData();
    Test.startTest();
    List<String> Prop = MessageTypeController.getProperties('isArray');
    System.debug('Test Category'+Prop);
    if(Prop!=null){
          System.assertEquals(Prop!=null,true);
    }else{
         System.assertEquals(Prop==null,true);  
    }
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

The text of the error is:

> "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getProperties(String)"

Comment: it's the getProperties('isArray')? I think parameter is wrong or something else when i save and push code got this error "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getProperties(String)"

Comment: What is the text of the error, like "Division by zero" or "Variable not found"?

Comment: method name is right but incorrect signature i don't understand..

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for the class `MessageTypeController`?

Comment: I assume this code is in Java. Are you using an IDE that can do full type introspection? Perhaps your IDE can tell you what parameters this method takes.

Comment: class name is also right and i'm using vscode

Comment: What should I Do?

Answer (score 0):

You / your colleague defined `getProperties(sObject objObject, string sFieldAPI)` but you're trying to call it with `getProperties('isArray')`. There's no method with 1 parameter (at least not in the code snippet you pasted).

You probably want to call it with something like

```
MessageTypeController.getProperties(new Opportunity(), 'StageName');
```

Comment: I already tried with two parameter still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

With this now it's working:

```
testMethod static void testGetProperties(){
    setupInsertData();
    Test.startTest();
    skyvvasolutions__MessageType__c msg = new skyvvasolutions__MessageType__c();
    List<String> Prop = MessageTypeController.getProperties(msg, 'skyvvasolutions__Properties__c');
    System.debug('Test Category'+Prop);
    if(Prop!=null){
          System.assertEquals(Prop!=null,true);
    }else{
         System.assertEquals(Prop==null,true);  
    }
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

Comment: So... this is with two parameters, as in my answer, right? ;)

Comment: yes it take two parameters but not the way you showed.

Comment: Different how? That you have `skyvvasolutions__MessageType__c msg = new skyvvasolutions__MessageType__c()` in separate line? A variable you don't use anywhere else in the test? Or that you made it run on different sObject? lol

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).